# Procedure for Bjørnland & Leitemo (2009) methodology in R

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I've been looking for a solution in `R` to estimate a structural VAR with long and short run restrictions as done in [Bjørnland & Leitemo (2009)](https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/moneco/v56y2009i2p275-282.html), where they represent a stable VAR in a moving average form:

$$
y_t=B(L)u_t
$$
where $B(L)$ is a convergent matrix polynomial in L (the lag operator), representing the long-run dynamics of the model.

Assuming the reduced-form residuals $u_t$ are linear combinations of the structural errors $\varepsilon_t$, i.e. $u_t=S\varepsilon_t$, they arrive at

$$
y_t=B(L)S\varepsilon_t
$$
$S$, then, describing the short-run dynamics.

The authors then impose a series of restrictions on $S$ and one in $B$, totalizing the needed number of restrictions for just-identification. I've found a `RATS`[script](https://estima.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1118) that reproduces their work, but nothing similar in `R`. I know that in `R` the `vars` package allows for the estimation of AB-models, which relates the errors mentioned above as $Au_t=B\varepsilon_t$, but I'm not sure how this (and if) could help me reproduce such methodology. I'm about to use the `RATS` script for guidance and implement the methodology in `R` from scratch, but I thought it was a good idea to first check if someone here could suggest me an easier path.